Importing dump data to neo4j
I am following the rules on here: https://github.com/neo4j-graph-examples/stackoverflow?tab=readme-ov-file
And after implementing this command in terminal: NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-admin load --from data/stackoverflow-4-3-1.dump [--database "database"]
I get this error:-bash: NEO4J-HOME/bin/neo4j-admin: No such file or directory
Also, NEO4J_HOME is a variable that points to the directory where neo4j is installed and it is set properly. Any idea on how I can solve this?? Thanks in advance

Alright, I found the answer to the question: Add the data file and then create the DBMS as mentioned in the post. That is it! No need to follow further steps; the graph is already created in the database. Hopefully this helps everyone. Also, I am using Neo4j Desktop and not aura.
